# How to count specific and maximum values in multiple columns in a data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, stata, data-wrangling

I would like to count how many values there are between 3 and 15 in the sets between `A`, `C`, and `E` variables and put them in a new variable (`newVar`).

Also, I would need to know what is the maximum value between these variables and put it in a new column (maxVar).

Note: In the real database, the name of the variables do not follow a pattern and I need to specify one by one.

| id | varA | varB | varC | varD | varE | **newVar** | **maxVar** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 12 | 2 | 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 | 8 | 3 | 7 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 1 | 0 | 11 | 2 | 11 |
| 4 | 8 | 7 | 7 | 4 | 2 | 2 | 8 |
| 5 | 0 | 3 | 0 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 6 | 3 | 7 | 15 | 9 | 11 | 3 | 15 |

In Stata, it is possible to do it using the commands:

`egen newVar = anycount (varA varC varE), values (3/15)`

`egen maxVar = rowmax (varA varC varE)`

How can I do the same thing in R?

Comment: The space before the parentheses in each function and option call is legal but poor or at least non-standard style.

Answer (score 1):

What about this in base R:

```r
rowSums(((df >= 3) * (df <= 15))[, grepl("[ACE]$", colnames(df))])
#> [1] 2 3 2 2 0 3
```

EDIT

Not pretty, but works

```r
df |>
  (\(x) list(
      x = x,
      rowSums(((x >= 3) * (x <= 15))[, c("varA", "varC", "varE")]),
      apply(x[, c("varA", "varC", "varE")], 1, max)
    ))() |>

  (\(x) Reduce(cbind, x) |>
     `colnames<-`(c(colnames(df), c("newVar", "maxVar"))))()
#>   id varA varB varC varD varE newVar maxVar
#> 1  1    3    5    7   12    2      2      7
#> 2  2    4    8    3    7    4      3      4
#> 3  3    6    9    1    0   11      2     11
#> 4  4    8    7    7    4    2      2      8
#> 5  5    0    3    0    2    1      0      1
#> 6  6    3    7   15    9   11      3     15
```

Comment: Sorry, I ended up not mentioning that in the actual database, variables are not consecutive and do not follow a pattern. I also updated the question by adding one more related question. If you can help me, I would be very grateful!

Comment: This does not require that the columns are in order. It doesn't have to be a fixed pattern, you can use literal column names for the index.

Comment: I updated to include the new requirements. Note that I would definitely do this with one of the tidyverse solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df %>%
    mutate(newVar = rowSums(between(select(., ends_with(c("A", "C", "E"))), 3, 15)))
```

or

```
df %>%
    mutate(newVar = rowSums(between(select(., matches("[ACE]$")), 3, 15)))
```

which gives

```
  id varA varB varC varD varE newVar
1  1    3    5    7   12    2      2
2  2    4    8    3    7    4      3
3  3    6    9    1    0   11      2
4  4    8    7    7    4    2      2
5  5    0    3    0    2    1      0
6  6    3    7   15    9   11      3
```

Comment: Sorry, I ended up not mentioning that in the actual database, variables are not consecutive and do not follow a pattern. I also updated the question by adding one more related question. If you can help me, I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively with `length` and `which`

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% rowwise() %>% rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(newvar=length(which(across(c(varA,varC,varE)) %in% c(3:15))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-15 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 6 × 7
# Rowwise: 
     id  varA  varB  varC  varD  varE newvar
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1     3     5     7    12     2      2
2     2     4     8     3     7     4      3
3     3     6     9     1     0    11      2
4     4     8     7     7     4     2      2
5     5     0     3     0     2     1      0
6     6     3     7    15     9    11      3
```